# Code Bug: Segmentation Fault [EVERYTIME]

Tags: c

I am writing this C/C++ program that is suppose to find the mean, median, and mode of a varied size array.  Although, I keep getting a Segmentation Fault regardless of the input.  What is wrong with my code?  Any suggestions always appreciated! :)

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
//#include <string.h>
//#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

Prototypes:

```
void sort(double*[],int);
static int min(double,double[],int);
double mean(double[],int);
double median(double[],int);
double mode(double[],int);
int numberOf(double,double[],int);
```

Main Function:

```
int main() {
    int i;
    scanf(" %d ",&i); //10
    double arr[i]; //array that contains all the values and will be sortted
    for (int j=0; j<i; j++) { //64630 11735 14216 99233 14470 4978 73429 38120 51135 67060
        scanf(" %lf ",&arr[j]);
    }
    printf("%.1lf\n%.1lf\n%.0lf",mean(arr,i),median(arr,i),mode(arr,i));
    return 0;
}
```

Sort Function:
    The end result should update the array arr from the call in the Median Function.  Changes the used values in the original array to -1 until that is the entire array.

```
void sort(double* arr[],int l) {
    double arr2[l];
    for (int i=0; i<l; i++) {
        int j;
        if (i)
            j = min(arr2[i-1], *arr, l);
        else
            j = min(0, *arr, l);
        arr2[i] = *arr[j];
        *arr[j] = -1;
    }
    for (int i=0; i<l; i++) {
        *arr[i] = arr2[i];
    }
}
```

Min Function (helper function for the Sort Function):
    Finds the minimum value amongst the array elements that is greater than or equal to *minLookingTo*
    Returns the position the value is in.

```
static int min(double minLookingTo,double arr[],int l) {
    int minP;
    double minA = minLookingTo;
    for (int i=0; i<l; i++) {
        if (arr[i] == -1)
            continue;
        if (minLookingTo<=arr[i] && arr[i]<=minA) {
            minP = i;
            minA = arr[i];
        }
    }
    return minP;
}
```

Mean Function:
    Returns the mean of the inputted array with the length *l*

```
double mean(double arr[],int l){
    double total = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<l; i++) {
        total += arr[i];
    }
    return total/l;
}
```

Median Function:
    Uses the Sort Function.  Assuming that works, returns the median.

```
double median(double arr[],int l){
    sort(&arr,l);
    double d = arr[(l/2)+1];
    double dd = arr[(l/2)];
    if (l%2!=0)
        return d;
    return (d+dd)/2;
}
```

Mode Function:
    Uses the NumberOf Function to determine the array element with the maximum amount of repeats.  Returns the lowest value of the highest (equal) repeats.

```
double mode(double arr[],int l){
    int maxA;
    int maxP;
    for (int i=0;i<l;i++) {
        int j = numberOf(arr[i],arr,l);
        if (j>maxA) {
            maxA = j;
            maxP = i;
        }
        else if (j==maxA && arr[maxP]>arr[i])
            maxP = i;
    }
    double d = arr[maxP];
    return d;
}
```

NumberOf Function:
    Helper function for the Mode Function.  Returns the amount of elements with the *looking* value.

```
int numberOf(double looking,double arr[],int l) {
    int amount = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<l; i++)
        if (looking == arr[i])
            amount++;
    return amount;
}
```

Comment: One suggestion, run your code in a debugger

Comment: These aren't the wrong things you're looking for, but I can tell you that: 1. You're using `scanf`, [which is notoriously hard to use](http://www.c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html).  2. Ugh, please don't use a lowercase L for variable names. 3. It doesn't seem like you've given any effort into isolating what part of your code is failing, and in this case it shouldn't take much.

Comment: You've tagged the question as C and C++ so we can't tell which language/compiler you are using, and you don't identify where the crash happens so you are apparently too lazy to have used the debugger even once.

Comment: Present your code as a program that we can compile not broken into a collection of incoherent parts. Edit your post to present us with a program that we can compile and perhaps we can help you.

Comment: There is no such thing as a *C/C++* program. It can't possibly be written in both languages at the same time, because they're not the same language. Pick the one you're actually using, and use only that tag. If you're unsure which one you're using, step away from the keyboard until you figure it out. Once you have, fix the tags and text, and include a [mcve] that will demonstrate the problem.

Comment: It must be C code because it reads `i` and then uses `double arr[i];` in the `main()` function.  Only C allows that officially; the G++ compiler also allows it unless you're using `-pedantic`, but that's not standard C++.  Even so, there needs to be an MCVE ([MCVE]) as you've already been told.

Comment: With `int maxA; ...  if (j>maxA) {` what if the value of `maxA`?

Comment: With `j = min(0, *arr, l);  arr2[i] = *arr[j];`, what is the value of `arr[j]`?  Save time, enable compiler warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tracked your segmentation fault to your `sort()` routine called by `median()`.  Rather than fix `sort()`, I substituted `qsort()` from the library to convince myself that's the problem:

```
// Median Function:
// Uses the Sort Function. Assuming that works, returns the median.

int comparator(const void *p, const void *q) {

    double a = *((double *) p);
    double b = *((double *) q);

    return (a > b) - (a < b); // compare idiom
}

double median(double array[], int length) { 
    // sort(array, length);

    qsort(array, length, sizeof(double), &comparator);

    double d = array[length / 2];

    if (length % 2 != 0) {
        return d;
    }

    double dd = array[(length / 2) - 1];

    return (d + dd) / 2;
}
```

For the example list of numbers provided, after correcting the rest of the code, this returns a median of 44627.5

**Other fixes:**

You're missing a final newline here:

```
printf("%.1lf\n%.1lf\n%.0lf",mean(arr,i),median(arr,i),mode(arr,i));
```

You should probably initialize the variables in `mode()`:

```
double mode(double array[], int length) {
    int maxA = INT_MIN;
    int maxP = -1;

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        int j = numberOf(array[i], array, length);

        if (j > maxA) {
            maxA = j;
            maxP = i;
        } else if (j == maxA && array[maxP] > array[i]) {
            maxP = i;
        }
    }

    return array[maxP];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code has a series of errors. Some of them:

1. You don´t need (in this case) to use spaces in scanf. This is causing a reading error.
2. You don't need to pass an array address to a function in order to alter its values. Arrays are always passed by reference. So change your function from `void sort(double*[],int);` to `void sort(double[],int);`, make the necessary corrections inside the function and call it using `sort(arr,l);` instead of `sort(&arr,l);`
3. Your min() function declares an uninitialized variable `minP`, so this variable contains garbage from your memory. The for() loop isn't entering none of the both if() conditions, so your function ends and returns the still uninitialized variable `minP`. This random value is then used to access an index in your array: `j = min(0, arr, l);` min returns an random number and then `arr2[i] = arr[j];` accessing forbidden memory region, which is causing your segmentation fault error. The same problem is occurring with the variables `maxP` and `maxA` in the `mode()` function.

You must always be careful when accessing your arrays to not go beyond its bounds and always be sure that variables will be initialized when using them. And as others have commented, I also highly recommend you to learn how to debug your programs, since this will help you to analyze its execution and trace bugs.

Comment: And compiling with enough warnings enabled allows the compiler to assist.  It warns me about `minP` — but also `maxP` and `maxA` too.  (I used `gcc -O3   -g      -std=c11   -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes  -Wold-style-definition       -c mess11.c` after fixing it to `int main(void)`.)

Comment: Detail, "... spaces in scanf. This is causing a reading error." --> It is the trailing spaces in the format that cause the problem.  The leading ones are only unneeded.